# Special letter in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents, characters

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccentii}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}\mkern3mu#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent}[2]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    ##\cr
    \hidewidth$\scriptstyle#1$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.5ex}
    $#2$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\acuteddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentii{\acute}{#1}}
\begin{flushleft}
\sloppy
\justify
$a_{\acuteddot{x}}$
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

This code is working fine. But if I use `$\acuteddot{x}$` in index e.g: `$a_{\acuteddot{x}}$` it does not resize itself. But if I use `$a_{d}$` it resize itself. How could I do that, to resize itseft like ordinary stuffs. This special character could be anywhere, it could be subscript's subscript.

I am using: MiKTeX, texmaker, win10 64bit

Comment: Please, can you add a full compilable code instead of a fragment? What packages do you use?

Comment: I have just edited my post

Comment: Now I am using \DeclareRobustCommand{\acuteddot}[1]{\genericmathaccentii{\acute}{#1}} but it still not resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the Humgarian double-acute accent, in PDFTeX, it’s in the T1 font encoding. (**Edit:** or in OT1, which is already loaded by default, although I believe some packages might change that.)  You can declare it as a math-mode accent:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{accents}

\DeclareSymbolFont{t1letters}{T1}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{t1letters}{bold}{T1}{\rmdefault}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mathdacute}{\mathalpha}{t1letters}{"05}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\sloppy
\justify
$a_{\mathdacute{\alpha}_{\mathdacute{x}}} \boldsymbol{\mathdacute{u}}$
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

If you don’t like the placement of the accents, `\skew` it.

This uses up one of the sixteen math alphabets you’re allowed in classic TeX.  If you don’t need uppercase Greek in `\mathrm`, you could instead redefine that to use T1 encoding.

If you can upgrade to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and use Unicode, that will be a more robust solution.

If you are looking for a generic macro to typeset two arbitrary accents side-by-side above a symbol, you could use `\text` to get a scaling box, or `\mathchoice` to select the appropriate math style within the box.

Comment: I don't really see the need for a symbol font. `\DeclareMathAccent{\mathdacute}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"7D}` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: It’s also in OT1, and by default `operators` is set to that. I believe there are packages that change it, however.

Answer (score 1):

No need to define new symbol fonts, because the long umlaut is available in the OT1 encoding.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmap}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{amsfonts} % already loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{accents}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % do you need it?

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % do you need it?
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % not needed for the example

\DeclareMathAccent{\acuteddot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{125}

\begin{document}

$a_{\acuteddot{x}}+\acuteddot{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have reorganized your preamble. I'm not sure why using `flushleft` and then declaring `\justify` inside it, as justification is the standard typesetting mode.

Where to find the magic number 125? Either consulting a font table or looking into `ot1enc.def` that has the line

```
\DeclareTextAccent{\H}{OT1}{125}
```

and we know that `\H` is the command for the long umlaut.

Just for completeness, here's how you might define the accent with the manual way you found (and that's not the best definition).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{amsfonts} % already loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{accents}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % do you need it?

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % do you need it?
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % not needed for the example

\DeclareMathAccent{\acuteddot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{125}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\genericmathaccentii}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent{#1{}\mkern3mu#1{}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\genericmathaccent@{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent@}[2]{%
  \genericmathaccent@@#1#2%
}
\newcommand{\genericmathaccent@@}[3]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$#1#3$}%
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      \hidewidth$\m@th#1#2{}$\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\ht\z@}
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\demotestyle@}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\acuteddotalt}[1]{\genericmathaccentii{\acute}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$a_{\acuteddot{x}}+\acuteddot{x}$

$a_{\acuteddotalt{x}}+\acuteddotalt{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]